lwc event handler not able to take even params from child
I have a child component
BoatSearchForm.html and a parent component BoatSearch.html which embeds the child and listens to its "onsearch" event. While listening it tries to get the value of params from the event and update its variable "boatFromSearch"
I am facing the issue of extracting the value from the event.
When I do boatFromSearch = evt.detail.key, the value is still not coming as "detail-value"
BoatSearchForm.html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Find a Boat" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_align-center">
            <lightning-combobox
                name="boatTypeOptions"
                placeholder="All Types"
                value={selectedBoatType}
                options={boatTypes}
                onchange={handleBoatTypeChange}
                variant="label-hidden">
            </lightning-combobox>
            <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_small" variant="brand" label="Search" onclick={handleSearch} data-id="search-button"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_small" variant="neutral" label="New" onclick={handleNewClick}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    <p>checking the selction {testselection}</p>
</template>
  

boatSearchForm.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class BoatSearch extends LightningElement {
    boatTypes = [{label:"TypeA", value:"TypeA", key : "TypeA"}, {label:"TypeB", value:"TypeB", key:"TypeB"}, {label:"TypeC", value:"TypeC", key:"TypeC"}]
    boats = [{"Id": 1, "Contact":{"Name": "Aastha"}, "BoatType":"TypeA"}, {"Id":2, "Contact": {"Name": "Paruthi", "BoatType":"TypeB"}}]

    testselection = "abc"

    // Handles change in boat type
    handleBoatTypeChange(event) {
        this.selectedBoatType = event.detail.value;
        this.testselection = this.selectedBoatType
    }

    // Method to handle search button click
    handleSearch() {
        var searchEvent = new CustomEvent('search', {
            detail: {
              key: 'detail-value'
            }
          });
        this.dispatchEvent(searchEvent);
    }
}


boatSearch.html
<template>
    <lightning-layout>
      <lightning-layout-item class="slds-align-middle" onclick = {handleSearch}>
        <c-boat-search-form onsearch={handleSearch}></c-boat-search-form>
        <c-boat-search-results></c-boat-search-results>
      </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
    <p>The boat type being passed to parent is {boatFromSearch} checking in v17</p>
  </template>

boatSearch.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class BoatSearch extends LightningElement {
    boats = [{"Id": 1, "Contact":{"Name": "Riya"}}, {"Id":2, "Contact": {"Name": "Parut"}}]
    boatFromSearch = "old";

    handleSearch(evt)
    {
        this.boatFromSearch = evt.detail.key; 
    }
}

I have tried referring multiple resources and the syntax seems fine to me, still not able to find the issue.

Why are you calling handleSearch on both the click event of your lightning-layout-item as well as the search event of your c-boat-search-form element?
